# Stopping the program for a period of time in tkinter with python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am wondering if I can pause my python program for 1 second - not using regular python, using the Tkinter module - I would like to change the name of a label after 1 second. How can I do this?

Comment: you don't need to pause the program. There are many questions and answers on this site about updating labels after a period of time. Have you done any searches before asking?

Comment: @eyllanesc: your comment is going  to not make much sense to a beginner, because tkinter has no Clock class or function.

Comment: It is like another but I would like more information, please - some syntax maybe.

Comment: @BryanOakley I got confused with pygame

Comment: read about `after` method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17628191/basic-timer-in-tkinter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Basic timer in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17628191/basic-timer-in-tkinter)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to schedule an action for one second later.
It's pretty different from pausing the program, and you actually don't need to do so.

The `tkinter.Widget.after` method is pretty much what you're looking for.
It accepts a callback (that is, a function to be called), and a delay after which the former should be called.

So you need a function to set the text of the label:

```
def set_text():
    label['text'] = "A new text"
```

You will then pass it as second argument to the `after` method of your root widget, the first argument being the delay in milliseconds:

```
root.after(1000, set_text)
```

This will schedule a call to the `set_text` function, one second later.

Here is a complete example, demonstrating the effect of the `after` method.
A label with `Initial text` will be displayed, and after one second, its text will change to `A new text`.

```
import tkinter as tk

def set_text():
    label['text'] = "A new text"

root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root, text="Initial text")

label.pack()
root.after(1000, set_text)

root.mainloop()
```